# is there any way to get focus on TextFeild when validation error occurs flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to get focus on TextFeild when validation error occurs in flutter,is there any way to get focus on TextFeild when validation error occurs in flutter?

Answer (score 1):

You can move focus around with FocusNode and requestFocus(). You can find the documentation [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/focus)

TextField(
focusNode: myFocusNode
)

Comment: Thank you for your help!!                                                                                                but it returns focus to multiple field I want to check which text field has error and focus it if it is not valid

Comment: I think you have to define a focus node for each field. And keep trak of witch error goes on witch field.